# SVG scale absolute size

Tags: svg

I am trying to display multiple SVG items in the same size, but each SVG item seems to have completely arbitrary size. Setting width/height to the top element did not work. Only `transform=scale()` worked, but since the argument of scale is ratio, that means that I have to specify different ratio to each item to make them the same size. So, instead of scaling them by ratio, is there any way to scale them to absolute size? Something like "scale to width 100px and height 100px", instead of "scale to 10% width and 10% height".

---

Mr Michael Mullany, I had tried that before posting this, but it did not work. Did I miss something?

1. NZ flag was very big and setting size made only the top/left show up:

[image]
[image]

2. Swiss flag was very small and setting the size did not enlarge it:

[image]
[image]

Comment: No, I don't think that's how SVG works, because that kind of scaling operation would require to first draw the thing in some "native" size, then see how much that differs from the desired size, then calculate a correction factor for all coordinates (which is effectively scaling to some percentage of the original size), and redrawing it. And SVG supports effects which are scale-invariant but affect an object's bounding box, so this is mathematically impossible, as far as I can tell!

Comment: Your problem is with viewBox, not sure if you actually used inkscape to make these and then changed the viewBox yourself afterwards but the SVG images will be the same size with width and height attributes as long as their viewBoxes are correcly sized to the image. I can tell that neither of these had a 100 x 100 artboard when they were created. If you have original SVG code then share that in a code snippet (not a picture of the code) and someone can easily help you display 2 differently sized SVG in the same size.

Answer (score 0):

**Not** an expert on SVG, but:

No, I don't think that's how SVG works, because that kind of scaling operation would require to first draw the thing in some "native" size, then see how much that differs from the desired size, then calculate a correction factor for all coordinates (which is effectively scaling to some percentage of the original size), and redrawing it. And SVG supports effects which are scale-invariant but affect an object's bounding box, so this is mathematically impossible, as far as I can tell!

Comment: So, what can I do?  GetBBox/getboundary(forgot the exact name) seem to return 0, because I am creating the SVG images dynamically by loading from XML., so I cannot know the size to calculate the different scales to make the same final size.

Answer (score 0):

I might not be understanding the question - but is there a reason why you wouldn't use SVG's built-in image element, specifying width and height? (And no preservation of the aspect ratio - which is what I think you want?)

```
<svg width="1000px" height="1000px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <image x="0" y="0" width="100" height-"100" xlink:href="http://yourdomain.com/yourimage.svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please see the appended part of the original question. That did not work.

Comment: Convert the incoming SVG/XML into an inline data URI and use this structure.